# Sparklyr - change log level in spark-submit

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

What I am trying to achieve is to silence all the information logged to the console during ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit execution.

I have already changed log level for spark itself by changing the appropriate line in ${SPARK_HOME}/conf/log4j.properties but still when I submit my R-sparklyr-script along with sparklyr.jar to execute as a sort of standalone job I get the following info:

########

[user@host] ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --class sparklyr.Shell 'sparklyr.jar' script.R
21/07/01 16:12:25 INFO sparklyr: Session (999991) is starting under 127.0.0.1 port 4440
21/07/01 16:12:25 INFO sparklyr: Session (999991) found port 4440 is available
21/07/01 16:12:26 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (999991) is starting batch rscript
....

########

I deducted that sparklyr uses log4j as a logger but I don't know where to find the appropriate log4j.properites file to change log level.

Do you know any method to cope with it?

With regards,
Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that I was a little bit wrong about sparklyr using log4j. Anyway it seems that developers will try to look into that problem in the future.

https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/3145